# 1 : 1 Mapping of integers to decimals

Tags: real-numbers, infinity, integers, transfinite-recursion

First question here so please point me in the right direction if I'm doing this wrong.

The basic premise of my question is this : if we take any decimal number such as 0.02053 and "reflect" it about the decimal point the result is 35020.

It appears as if there are no decimals between 0 and 1 which cannot be manipulated in this way to give a unique result since even irrational numbers would simply create an infinitely large (but unique) number.

If we continue down this line of thought we can deduce that there is a 1:1 mapping between all decimals between 0 and 1 to all the integers.

I know this result is false but I'm unsure where my logic is slipping up.

Any answers are much appreciated :)

Comment: There are no integers with infinitely many digits.

Comment: What is the natural number corresponding to $1/3$?

Comment: Is a number with infinitely many digits not natural? If I had to correspond 1/3 to an integer then I would say that it's an infinite number of 3's, or something like 3×sum(10^(n)) from 0 to infinity. Are numbers with infinitely many digits not natural? If so, why not? My understanding was that any number which doesn't include a decimal component is an integer.

Comment: Yes, but ...333 is not a real number. The sum you wrote there does not converge in the real numbers.

Comment: Ah I see - if a number is infinitely large then it's no longer considered an integer. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: The number $...333$ would be something expressed as $3+3\cdot 10+3\cdot 10^2+...$ which is a divergent series. Not a number at all, not just non-integer